# Autocorrelation chip

Tags: signal-processing

Does there exist a chip that will do autocorrelation over a data sample of several thousand points? I need to find the place in the data sample which most closely matches a given waveform (that I provide) At worst it is about 10k samples to match against a sample pattern of around 1k samples. Ideally I need to do this in well under 1mS.
I seem to recall that this was once done in h/w, but cannot find the correct search terms to turn up any contemporary chips.

Comment: Can you 'threshold' the samples, and reduce it to a bit pattern search? Then a quick 32bit MCU (e.g. ARM Cortex-M4, PIC32MZ, or better, such as BlackFin) may be able to do it. Some students did GPS autocorreletation on a BlackFin.

Comment: I already have a Cortex-M4 and it is not as fast as I would like, hence the question. At worst, I have about 10k samples to match against a sample pattern of around 1k samples. IIRC it used to be done with shift registers and dedicated logic. I would have thought there is still a need for such h/w implementations

Comment: I suppose the obvious answer is use an FPGA, but I imagine you know that. So I am adding this comment for completeness. One way to get something which might do much of the processing might be to get a [Parallella](http://www.adapteva.com/parallella-board/). [RS sell them](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/processor-microcontroller-development-kits/8194702/). It has a Xilinx Zynq FPGA fabric, two 800MHz ARM-A9, and 16 800MHz 'Array processor'. There should be enough memory on the array processor to solve the problem. Edit: I believe it is mostly shift registers, xor and bit counting.

Comment: Also, would you add the "about 10k samples to match against a sample pattern of around 1k samples" back into your question. It makes the scale of the problem clearer.

Comment: @gbulmer Learning curve on the Zynq is a bit steep, but you can do a lot with it.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany - agreed, I haven't got there :-) However, the Parallella's 16 core Epiphany is programmable in C, and there may have been enough community activity to make poring data into it (via the FPGA fabric) feasible.

Comment: Are you aware of the relationship between [autocorrelation and FFT](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/10858)?

Comment: Yes - I have been reading about it. Now all I have to do is learn to do a FFT and IFFT and convolution on 10k data points :-(

Answer (score 4):

I think you actually want *cross-correlation* rather than *auto-correlation*, since two signals are involved.

Search for VHDL or Verilog and "cross-correlation" for hardware description language methods.

An FPGA would be one way of doing it, if your ARM isn't fast enough.

Comment: There is only really one signal involved because it is the early part of this that I am trying to compare against later samples to find the closest point where the waveform repeats. However, doing my own h/w implementation is not feasible given the project overhead involved, hence my question with regard to a COTS solution.

Comment: You could get an eval board then it would be "just" code. LOL.

Comment: Setting up a Discovery board for the STM32F303 to do the prototype data acquisition is enough of a pain without adding another!

Answer (score 1):

Edit2: An FPGA is an obvious way to go. However, there may be a relatively cheap way to implement a fast FFT in software with off-the-shelf hardware using a Raspberry-Pi.

[ACCELERATING FOURIER TRANSFORMS USING THE GPU](http://www.raspberrypi.org/accelerating-fourier-transforms-using-the-gpu/) describes using the GPU on the Raspberry-Pi to do FFTs.

Quote:
"GPU_FFT is an FFT library for the Raspberry Pi which exploits the BCM2835 SoC V3D hardware to deliver **ten times the performance** that is possible on the **700 MHz ARM**."
That should be quick enough.

Quote:
"The library runs on dedicated 3D hardware in the BCM2835 SoC, and communication between ARM and GPU *adds 100µs of latency which is much longer than the shortest transform takes to compute*!"

So that might be available, affordable, ready-written and tested, and a big enough hammer to justify investigating it. There will be issues over jitter, as the CPU still runs Linux, though running the code on the GPU (maybe headless?) should reduce the problem a lot. I don't know about running R-Pi with a 'real-time' OS.

Edit: {
A GPGPU, programmed in e.g. CUDA or OpenCL, is fast enough to do the correlation, especially using FFT's.

Edit: Host-to-GPU latency, i.e. getting data in and out was fast, is still an issue, but has been significantly improved. 1ms appears to be viable including round trip latency. However it'd take some experiments to be comfortable the GPGPU is going to work. That is non-trivial if you aren't familiar with the programming techniques.

I am assuming a PC hosted solution isn't within your scope as an average multi-core PC should be able to 'smash this out of the park'.
} end edit.

However, one way to get something which might do **all** of the processing in software might be a [Parallella](http://www.adapteva.com/parallella-board/).

For example, [RS sell them](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/processor-microcontroller-development-kits/8194702/).

It has a Xilinx Zynq FPGA fabric, and two 800MHz ARM-A9.

Most relevant is its Epiphany 16-core, 800MHz/core, RISC, 'Array of processors'. The Epiphany processors are fully autonomous (so not like a GPU), each with its own program. However it does have a fast interconnect fabric which enables them to communicate very quickly, so the signal could be flowed through them.

There should be enough memory on the Epiphany processor array to solve the problem with a good degree of parallelism.

Epiphany is programmed in C.

Their is a lower-cost Epiphany with a lower-gate-count Zynq. It has all its FPGA committed to making the board work, especially the interface to Epiphany. So that board might be enough to solve this specific problem.

It is an Open Source board, with an active community, so there may have been enough activity to provide a way to 'pour' the data into Epiphany using the FPGA without VHDL hacking.

Though not relevant to your situation, the more expensive board provides significant uncommitted FPGA fabric, allowing users to exploit the performance of an FPGA, which may be important in the general case.

Side Note:
[GPS Demodulation and decoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Positioning_System#Demodulation_and_decoding) demodulates the satellite signal using Gold codes. Maybe their have been chips available to help do that using some form of correlation, and that is what you are remembering?

Answer (score 0):

You should do an FFT on both signals and then multiply FFT1 and complex conjugate of FFT2. Google is your friend for more details on this neat trick.

Raw cross-correlation has order n^2 time complexity, and FFT, n log n, so for several thousand points the benefits can be very substantial, depending on the lag range that you're interested in.

Special attention should be paid to wrap-around vs. truncation. For example, if your samples A and B are 1000 points long, and you are looking at correlation lag 100, do you want corr(A[100...1000],B[1...900]), or should the samples be wrapped around? I think the FFT method effectively wraps them around (I figured this out at one point but forgot the answer by now, so this is just my intuitive understanding, please correct the if I'm wrong, and I'm kind of curious).

Answer (score 0):

I think @SpehroPefany is right, you want the cross correlation between your reference signal and your input.  You can multiply two signals together to look for the cross correlation.  (What's the maximum frequency of interest?) If you still want to do the auto correlation, there's a neat trick to do a conditional auto-correlation*  You trigger your DSO up near the peak of the waveform.  (that's the condition... that at this point in time the signal was at some level (with some slope.))  You then average the signal.  It's not a "real" auto correlation in the sense that if you take the FFT of the real auto correlation function you get the frequency distribution.  And for this conditional case the FFT losses the high frequency points faster.  (I can add more detail if there is interest.)

- OK searching for conditional auto-correlation I only get stock market stuff... so this may not be the correct term.